# Uniform convergence on [0,a]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

On the interval $[0,1)$ there is a function sequence $(f_n)$ given by

$f_n=\frac {1} {1-x^n}$ , $x\in [0,1)$.

Now i want to show that for every $a\in (0,1)$,  $f_n$ converge uniformly on $[0,a]$. Now I know that it does not converge on the interval [0,1) because the derivative would not allow us to go to 0 when $n$ tends to infinity. But i thought that uniform convergence depends on the lowest value within the interval in this case 0. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that
$$
|\frac{1}{1-x^{n}} - 1| \leq |\frac{1}{1 - a^{n}} - 1| \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in [0,a]$.

Comment: The limitfunction is equal to 1 as n goes to infinity. Then how did you apply the inequality and changed a with x? And also the fraction goes to 0 and 0-1 =0?

Comment: 1) Yes, so there is a "$-1$" in the first term. 2) If $0 < a < 1$ then $a^{n} \to 0$. If $0 \leq x \leq a < 1$, then $x^{n} \leq a^{n}$ so $-x^{n} \geq -a^{n}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused that why would it converge uniformly on [0,a] and not on [0,1)?

Comment: If you want to know why then you can only resort to a proof!

Comment: I used the m test to see where the max will be , but the derivative of the function is not suitable to show that as n goes to infinity then the fraction will be zero. So now how can it be that for a different interval it will be uniform convergent?

Comment: @Mark, Some logic preliminary is required here :). If a theorem asserts that $P$ implies $Q$, can you use the theorem when $P$ does not hold? No! the theorem is **not applicable** in such a case!

Comment: yes so in this case what is the $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: If the hypothesis $P$ does not hold, from the theorem alone there is no way to tell whether the conclusion $Q$ holds or not. :)

Comment: ok sir , but which theorem do you mean